# Unusual SQL query

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to find a MySQL query for the following question:

> How many articles are being supplied by *exactly one* supllier

- The articles are in the table *artikel*
- The suppliers are in the table *leverancier*
- The table connecting them is the *inkart* table

[image]

The query I got so far is:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(artikel.art)
FROM
    artikel
        JOIN
    inkart ON artikel.art = inkart.art
        JOIN
    leverancier ON inkart.lev = leverancier.lev
GROUP BY artikel.art
HAVING COUNT(leverancier.lev) = 1
```

But this is giving me the wrong (no) result. I figured I have to use a subquery somewhere, but I have no idea how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to count unique `leverancier.lev`, this will give list of `artikel.art`

```
SELECT artikel.art
FROM   artikel
        JOIN inkart ON artikel.art = inkart.art
        JOIN leverancier ON inkart.lev = leverancier.lev
GROUP  BY artikel.art
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT leverancier.lev) = 1
```

if you want the count of articles,

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT artikel.art
    FROM   artikel
            JOIN inkart ON artikel.art = inkart.art
            JOIN leverancier ON inkart.lev = leverancier.lev
    GROUP  BY artikel.art
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT leverancier.lev) = 1
) a
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(artikel.art)
from artikel
where 1= (select count(*) from inkart
           join leverancier on inkart.lev=leverancier.lev
           where inkart.art=artikel.art
         )
```